# Recycler View not displaying the list

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

My `recyclerview` is not working and doesn't display the list I'm setting to it. Could you help me find out the problem ? Below are the `Fragment` and the `Adapter` that I've  created.

Fragment Class ->

```kotlin
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var recyclerViewHomeHome: RecyclerView
    lateinit var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager

    private val restaurantsInfoList = arrayListOf<Restaurant>(
        Restaurant("rohh", "4.5", "560/person", R.id.imgLogoLogin),
        Restaurant("rohh", "4.5", "560/person", R.id.imgLogoLogin),
        Restaurant("rohh", "4.5", "560/person", R.id.imgLogoLogin),
        Restaurant("rohh", "4.5", "560/person", R.id.imgLogoLogin),
        Restaurant("rohh", "4.5", "560/person", R.id.imgLogoLogin),
        Restaurant("rohh", "4.5", "560/person", R.id.imgLogoLogin),
        Restaurant("rohh", "4.5", "560/person", R.id.imgLogoLogin)

    )

    lateinit var recyclerAdapter: HomeRecyclerAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        recyclerViewHomeHome = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewHomeHome)
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        recyclerAdapter = HomeRecyclerAdapter(activity as Context, restaurantsInfoList)

    }
return view
}
```

Adapter Class ->

```kotlin
class HomeRecyclerAdapter(val context: Context, val itemList: ArrayList<Restaurant>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeRecyclerAdapter.homeViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): homeViewHolder {

        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_single_row_item, parent, false)
        return homeViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return itemList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: homeViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val restaurant = itemList[position]
        holder.txtRestaurantNameSingle.text = restaurant.name
        holder.txtPriceSingle.text = restaurant.cost_for_one
        holder.imgRecyclerViewSingle.setBackgroundResource(restaurant.image_url)
        holder.ratingRecyclerViewSingle.text = restaurant.rating

    }

    class homeViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val txtRestaurantNameSingle: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtRestaurantNameSingle)
        val txtPriceSingle: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtPriceSingle)
        val ratingRecyclerViewSingle: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.ratingRecyclerViewSingle)
        val imgRecyclerViewSingle: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imgRecyclerViewSingle)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you assign Adapter and LayoutManager for the RecyclerView anywher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the layout manager and adapter onto the `RecyclerView`:

```kotlin
    recyclerViewHomeHome = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewHomeHome)
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    recyclerAdapter = HomeRecyclerAdapter(activity as Context, restaurantsInfoList)
    recyclerViewHomeHome.layoutManager = layoutManager
    recyclerViewHomeHome.adapter = recyclerAdapter
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should refactor your code, and take a look at [recyclerview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

Here is what I'm proposing in refactor. You don't need to have context in your `HomeRecyclerAdapter` so just remove it.

So it should look something like that :

```kotlin
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var recyclerViewHomeHome: RecyclerView
    lateinit var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
    lateinit var recyclerAdapter: HomeRecyclerAdapter

    private val restaurantsInfoList = arrayListOf<Restaurant>(
            Restaurant("rohh", "4.5", "560/person", R.id.imgLogoLogin),
            Restaurant("rohh", "4.5", "560/person", R.id.imgLogoLogin),
            Restaurant("rohh", "4.5", "560/person", R.id.imgLogoLogin),
            Restaurant("rohh", "4.5", "560/person", R.id.imgLogoLogin),
            Restaurant("rohh", "4.5", "560/person", R.id.imgLogoLogin),
            Restaurant("rohh", "4.5", "560/person", R.id.imgLogoLogin),
            Restaurant("rohh", "4.5", "560/person", R.id.imgLogoLogin)

    )

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        recyclerViewHomeHome = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewHomeHome)
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerAdapter = HomeRecyclerAdapter(restaurantsInfoList)
        recyclerViewHomeHome.layout = layoutManager
        recyclerViewHomeHome.adapter = recyclerAdapter
        return view
    }

}
```

and for your adapter you can use a lot of kotlin strenght:

```kotlin
class HomeRecyclerAdapter(val itemList: ArrayList<Restaurant>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeRecyclerAdapter.homeViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): homeViewHolder {
        homeViewHolder.from(parent)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = itemList.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: homeViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val restaurant = itemList[position]
        holder.bind(restaurant)
    }

    class homeViewHolder private constructor(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val txtRestaurantNameSingle: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtRestaurantNameSingle)
        val txtPriceSingle: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtPriceSingle)
        val ratingRecyclerViewSingle: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.ratingRecyclerViewSingle)
        val imgRecyclerViewSingle: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imgRecyclerViewSingle)

        fun bind(item: Restaurant){
            txtRestaurantNameSingle.text = item.name
            txtPriceSingle.text = item.cost_for_one
            imgRecyclerViewSingle.setBackgroundResource(item.image_url)
            ratingRecyclerViewSingle.text = item.rating
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_single_row_item, parent, false)
                return homeViewHolder(view)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.
There was one simple mistake you made.
The crashing problem was that you were using the inflator wrongly. I downloaded your project and deleted all the unnecessary methods and variables to highlight the problem. 
I assume you're a beginner but that's ok, that's why I put a few tips on the comments.

Note that the repo only contains the java files.

https://github.com/MicroRJ/BenzinpreiseApp-fixed

```
//Here was the problem 
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row_prices, parent, false));
}
```

If you need more help let me know. Btw, what is the app for? Seems cool.